# Distributed Java compilation of Android source code, is it possible?

Tags: java, android, compilation, distributed

Our company has realize its own tool of distributed compilation (compiled on several *NON-local* computers) for **Android** source code.

Now we have already realize the distributed compilation for the **C and C++** part of source code (in using Open Source's  **distcc** and **icecc**), but haven't done for the **Java** part.

Does anyone know if it is possible to realize the distributed compilation of Java ? Are there any limitations or problems of dependencies ? Are there any Open Source tools which could help to do this ?

Comment: Dude... why did you post the question in French then ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake to put it also in French. Because I thought perhaps there will be someone who are on Stackoverflow understanding only French could help me also. Thanks for deleting the French topic. :]

Comment: Does anybody give some tips ? Thanks a lot.